# Truncate Mongo Collection from Databricks

Tags: python, azure, databricks

I need to erase the from a MongoDB Collection (not delete the collection)

```
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient
  
# Making Connection
myclient = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://****@****.g56cp.mongodb.net")
  
# database
db = myclient["intellitur"]
  
# Created or Switched to collection
Collection = db["calendari_jar"]

db.members.deleteMany("calendari_jar")`
```

But I get the message  'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'deleteMany' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.

What do I have wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Try `Collection.delete_many(<filter>)`.

Comment: I need to erase everything inside the Collection.  I tried to use * in the filter, but I get the same error message  .. 'Collection' objec.t is not callable ...

Comment: Are you using `Collection` variable or `db` variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have decided to use DROP, because I didn't realise that I will not have problems with schemas because this is NoSQL.

My final code is:

```
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient
  
# Making Connection
myclient = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://ptddctti-dev:ptddctti-dev@ptddctti-mdb-cluster-pl-0.g56cp.mongodb.net")

# database
db = myclient["intellitur"]

# coleccion
Collection=db["calendari_jar"]
Collection.drop()
```